Intrinsic safety barrier - Zener power dissipation
I need some help with a question regarding intrinsic safety.
I have a device installed in an explosion-proof enclosure in Zone 1, which receives an intrinsically safe voltage of 24 V. The sensors connected to this device are powered through an intrinsic safety barrier, with a supply voltage of 12 V and a maximum circuit current consumption of 95 mA. The inherited circuit (only the input circuit and output to the inductive sensor remain):


Here are my questions:
1)The customer assures that the input voltage is intrinsically safe at 24 V. Does this mean that I don't need to consider the maximum voltage Um?
2)According to section 8.7 of standard IEC 60079-11, the Zener diode must be capable of conducting a continuous current equal to 1.7 times the rated value of the fuse (1.7 × 0.05 A = 0.085 A). If I use SMBJ15A (I understand that the current TVS diodes need to be replaced with Zener diodes), about 1.9 watts of power (P = 1.5 × 0.085 × 15) will be dissipated by it. How can I arrange efficient cooling?
3)Regarding the input circuit: The situation is problematic because the designer installed a 0.5 A fuse. Does this imply that I need to install a circuit with the same specifications as the customer's intrinsic safety barrier?
4)What should I do about the input capacitance? The capacitance at the device input must not exceed the maximum capacitance Co of the customer’s intrinsic safety barrier. This limit is significantly exceeded by 330 μF. According to Appendix A.3 of IEC60079-11, for Group IIB, only 2 μF is allowed. What should I do in this case?
Please excuse me if my questions seem foolish or incorrect. I have never worked with intrinsic safety before. Thank you in advance for your assistance!

If you plan to use 24V then having it continuously hooked up to 12V rated TVS is a plain bad design in general and a super bad idea for EX in particular. If the supply is 24V you should have a 12V switch regulator after the fuse + zener barrier which should then be placed on the 24V supply.

The Um is normally used for the NIS (Not IS), the signal going into the barrier.
On the barrier before your electronic you should know the Uo (12V), Io (?) and Po (?) since they are the values your equipment should be able to accept.
Your equipment should be marked with Ui, Ii and Pi.
VD21 and VD31 are not zener diodes but "Transient Voltage Suppressor Diode".
The 100 ohm resistor I would place after the fuse (Could be left out) since then you will only be able to receive Pmax = 12'12/100/4= 0,36W after the resistor. Imax = 12/100=120 mA
